# ASP.NET Core3.0, how to pass Enumerable user information List from the controller to _layout page (.cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

1. Once user login, thread go through the login verification
2. If the login exists in the database, the system will fetch the related role and assign actions to the particular role with menu items orders.
3. I have created a menu items list in the controller and in order to populate dynamic menu items, I need to pass the list of values from the controller to layout page.
4. My question is, I can't access the session list from the controller to the layout page.
5. however only a single value (string) can able to pass but the list I cant pass it.
6. Can anyone give me reply on how to pass the `IEnumerableList` through the session from the controller to .cshtml page.

Comment: Actually the above steps are helpful, but your coding is required here to find answers for developers..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to show you an example on how you can store and retrieve your complex objects like an `IEnumerable` in your `Session`:

In your Startup.cs, under the Configure method, add the following line:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
}
```

And under the `ConfigureServices` method, add the following line. You can set the timeout according to your own need:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //Added for session state
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

  services.AddSession(options =>
  {
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);               
  });
}
```

In order to store complex objects in your session in .NET Core:

Create a model class of your object type (For example `Student`):

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId{ get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a `SessionExtension` helper to set and retrieve your complex object as JSON:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
  public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
  {
    session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
  }

  public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
  {
    var value = session.GetString(key);
    return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
  }
}
```

Then finally set the complex object in your session as:

```
var student= new Student();
student.StudentId= "1";
student.StudentName = "Rahul";
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("StudentDetails", student);
```

To retrieve your complex object in your session:

```
var studentDetails= HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Student>("StudentDetails");
int studentId= Convert.ToInt32(studentDetails.StudentId);
string studentName= Convert.ToString(studentDetails.StudentName);
```

For your point 6:

> Can anyone give me reply on how to pass the `IEnumerableList` through the session from the controller to .cshtml page.

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation to your view and use it to get the Session object as required:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
<h1>@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Student>("StudentDetails");</h1>
```